# Why does powertop think I have two displays?

Tags: display, power-management, macbook, 12.04, powertop

Ok, so in `powertop` (version 1.97), in both the "overview" and "device stats" sections, I see two devices, each called "display backlight".  One shows the correct percentage of use, e.g. if I lower screen brightness then the use goes down, but the other is always at 100%!  The 100% one is always consuming around 2.3 watts, so of course I am interested in killing this thing off, whatever it is.

So my question is: why is powertop doing this?  Is there some technical way in which I do have two displays?  I have a MacBook Air, and I've *never* even once attached it to an external display.

**Update:**  Even stranger is that when I start up my system, the "display backlight" at 100% is only using 800-900 mW; however, over time, it will work its way up to 2.3 W.

Comment: No, that's not it.  I have all the ports turned off using powertop, but I still have that mysterious, extra "display backlight".

Comment: I don't see any reason here why you would think it's a bug and not a misconfiguration, as it turned out to be.  For the benefit of others who will run into the same issue, the solution is to install the proprietary Nvidia drivers.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a MacBook Pro running Leopard and Ubuntu 11.10 in dual boot. System monitor also gives me the same 2 cpu working, and I had one of them always at 100%. I changed the NVIDIA propietary driver to the "current-updates" version and it helped, now both cpu run around 30%. Also, battery life seems to have been extended and I have less heat problems (still, the laptop heats up way more when running Ubuntu than when running MacOS)

Comment: I should have paid closer attention to your answer.  The Nvidia proprietary driver solved my issue, which I thought was unrelated to yours.